# Where would I put CASE T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have this query below but I need to put a `CASE` somewhere in there that will make 'example,example' give an output of 'exampleexample' (minus the comma). Where would I put this? (I'm new to SQL)

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.ServerName, 'Standalone' AS Host, s.Status, s.Classification, 
                s.Location 
FROM tblSQLInstances i 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServer s
  on i.ServerName = s.ServerName
WHERE i.IsClustered = 0
  AND i.InstanceStatus != 'Demised'

UNION

SELECT esr.ServerName, e.EnvironmentDescription AS Host, s.Status, s.Classification, 
       s.Location  
from tblSQLEnvironmentServerRel esr
  INNER JOIN tblSQLEnvironments e
  ON esr.EnvironmentID = e.EnvironmentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServer s
  on esr.ServerName = s.ServerName
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSQLInstances i
  on i.EnvironmentID = e.EnvironmentID
WHERE i.InstanceStatus != 'Demised'
```

sorry if this makes little sense.

Comment: Which column returns 'example,example'? Is example an exact term, or should this remove any commas from the column. Also, which `sql` please (Oracle, MySql, SqlServer) ?

Comment: Err...depends where 'example,example' is supposed to be coming from. You'll not get any answers until we know what field it is in, what the data in the tables looks like etc. If one field already contains 'example,example' then you could simply use `REPLACE` although string operations are not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, if you wish to escape out commas out of one or more columns, you can use the `REPLACE` function. You can do this on the overall result of your union like so:

```
SELECT
   REPLACE(ServerName, ',', ''), 
   Host, 
   Status, 
   Classification, 
   Location 
FROM
(
   SELECT 

   DISTINCT i.ServerName, 'Standalone' AS Host, s.Status, s.Classification, 
            s.Location
   FROM tblSQLInstances i 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServer s
      on i.ServerName = s.ServerName
   WHERE i.IsClustered = 0
      AND i.InstanceStatus != 'Demised'

   UNION

   SELECT esr.ServerName, e.EnvironmentDescription AS Host, s.Status, 
          s.Classification, s.Location  
   FROM tblSQLEnvironmentServerRel esr
      INNER JOIN tblSQLEnvironments e
      ON esr.EnvironmentID = e.EnvironmentID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblServer s
      on esr.ServerName = s.ServerName
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSQLInstances i
      on i.EnvironmentID = e.EnvironmentID
   WHERE i.InstanceStatus != 'Demised'
) X;
```